# Can´t make outlet Swift IOS Development

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem i have 2 ViewController.swift files.

And in none of them i can make an outlet.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to restart Xcode?

Comment: Yes wait.. i try again

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure the `ViewController` class inspector in your canvas matches the `ViewController` class you want to make outlet to.

For example if you want to make an outlet in `SecondViewController` your `ViewController` in interface builder class inspector should be set to `SecondViewCotroller` too.

[image]

Now it works!

[image]

Comment: Im pretty new to coding can you show me how in pictures?

Comment: I have added a picture hope it helps.

Comment: Select your ViewController in **Interface Builder** then choose **Class Inspector**, then set the class to `SecondViewController` then load `SecondViewController` from assistant viewer ( as you did in the photo ) and finally do the outlet connection.

Comment: Which object i need to select? View Controller?

Comment: i will make a series of photo to show you how. hang on ;)